# How can I make messages (coming from the domain) format/markup ignorant?

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design

I want to send back formatted messages from my domain, For example things like:
(Bear with me this is not a real example, its just to illustrate my point)

> Hello Mr user, you cannot perform that
>   task because:
>
> 1. reason 1
> 2. reason 2
> 3. reason 3

I also want to show colors.

Right now I am sending it from the domain already marked up with HTML.

This seems wrong to me.  Because if I want to re-use that domain with a different front end, that may not be HTML aware, it will require different formatting and/or markup.

How can I design this so that my messages from the domain intended to be displayed on the user's screen can be markup ignorant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something *really simple* you could do something like this:

```
class DomainMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Color ForeColor { get; set; }
    public bool IsError { get; set; }
}
```

Or you could use the decorator pattern and create a message that way. You could then create a `DomainMessageWriter` that takes a domain message and spits out the right markup (ie `HtmlDomainMessageWriter`, `RtfDomainMessageWriter` etc).

HTH

Comment: I like the idea of a domain message writer, it could even be swapped out using IOC for a different implementation if used with a different front end.

Comment: @Roberto - Yeah exactly. You could also "apply" different styles to the `DomainMessage`. You could also have many other types of `DomainMessage`s too.